# Query which can round to the previous 30minutes interval

Tags: sql, oracle

I am querying database to get the results during 30minutes interval

1) Suppose if i am querying at 11:05am i should get the data from 10:30AM to 11:00AM
2) If I am querying at 11:35 I should get the data from 11:00AM TO 11;30AM.

In short I am looking for a query which can round to the previous 30minutes interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the difference between the `SYSDATE` and the `SYSDATE` truncated to the start of the hour; if it is greater than 30 minutes (1/48th of a day) then the start of the range is the `SYSDATE` truncated to the nearest hour otherwise it is the `SYSDATE` truncated to the nearest hour minus 30 minutes. The end of the range is just 30 minutes later.

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  date_column >= TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'HH24' )
                      - CASE WHEN SYSDATE - TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'HH24' ) >= 1/48
                             THEN 0
                             ELSE 1/48 END
AND    date_column <  TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'HH24' )
                      + CASE WHEN SYSDATE - TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'HH24' ) >= 1/48
                             THEN 1/48
                             ELSE 0 END;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with abcd as (select to_date('10:05','hh24:mi') test from dual 
               union all select to_date('10:30','hh24:mi') from dual 
               union all select to_date('10:31','hh24:mi') from dual               
               )
select trunc(test,'HH') trunc_date_to_hour , NUMTODSINTERVAL( round((test - trunc(test,'HH'))*24)/2, 'hour') minuts_to_add,trunc(test,'HH')+  NUMTODSINTERVAL( round((test - trunc(test,'HH'))*24)/2, 'hour')  from abcd;
```